# Normalize rows of pandas data frame by their sums

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing spectral data and metadata. The columns are labeled with a multiindex so that `df['wvl']` gives the spectra and `df['meta']` gives the metadata. Within `df['wvl']` the column labels are the wavelength values for the spectrometer channels.

What I want to do is normalize each row of `df['wvl']` by the sum of that row so that adding up the values in the row gives a total of 1.0.

Here's what one row of the dataframe looks like:

```
df['wvl'].iloc[0]
246.050003     128.533035
246.102005     102.756321
246.156006      99.930775
...    
848.697205     121.313347
848.896423     127.011662
849.095703     123.234168
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

But when I do something like:

```
df['wvl'].iloc[0]=df['wvl'].iloc[0]/df['wvl'].iloc[0].sum()
```

Nothing happens! I get the exact same values:

```
df['wvl'].iloc[0]
246.050003     128.533035
246.102005     102.756321
246.156006      99.930775
...    
848.697205     121.313347
848.896423     127.011662
849.095703     123.234168
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

If I create a temporary variable to hold the row, I can do the normalization just fine:

```
temp=df['wvl'].iloc[0]

temp=temp/temp.sum()

temp
246.050003    0.000027
246.102005    0.000022
246.156006    0.000021
                ...   
848.697205    0.000026
848.896423    0.000027
849.095703    0.000026
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

But if I try to replace the dataframe row with the normalized temporary variable, nothing happens:

```
df['wvl'].iloc[0]=temp

df['wvl'].iloc[0]
246.050003     128.533035
246.102005     102.756321
246.156006      99.930775
                 ...     
848.697205     121.313347
848.896423     127.011662
849.095703     123.234168
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I'm obviously missing something here, but I can't figure out what and it's driving me insane. Help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can use

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

`df.sum(axis=1)` sums up each row; `df.div(..., axis=0)` then divides.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
>>> df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
    a   b
0   0.250000    0.750000
1   0.333333    0.666667
```

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! Thanks! Could you help me understand why what I was doing was not working?

Comment: @eft773 So I tinkered around a bit, and it seems like the `iloc` is returning a copy, and, therefore, assignment to it does not change anything. Does this address your question?

Comment: Ahh, I see. I think that makes sense. So, essentially `df['wvl'].iloc[0]` is not actually a part of df['wvl'] anymore, so editing it does nothing to the original. Thank you!

Comment: is there any reasoning why `axis=1` is row sum yet `axis=1` is **column** division?