# how to get percentage of columns to sum of row in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, percentage

I have a very high dimensional data with more than 100 columns. As an example, I am sharing the simplified version of it given as a below:

```
date    product price   amount
11/17/2019  A   10  20
11/24/2019  A   10  20
12/22/2020  A   20  30
15/12/2019  C   40  50
02/12/2020  C   40  50
```

I am trying to calculate the percentage of columns based on total row sum illustrated below:

```
date    product price   amount
11/17/2019  A   10/(10+20)  20/(10+20)
11/24/2019  A   10/(10+20)  20/(10+20)
12/22/2020  A   20/(20+30)  30/(20+30)
15/12/2019  C   40/(40+50)  50/(40+50)
02/12/2020  C   40/(40+50)  50/(40+50)
```

Is there any way to do this efficiently for high dimensional data? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provided link ([Normalize rows of pandas data frame by their sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678874/normalize-rows-of-pandas-data-frame-by-their-sums)), you need to locate the specific columns as your first two column are non-numeric:

```
cols = df.columns[2:]
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0)
Out[1]: 
         date product              price             amount
0  11/17/2019       A 0.3333333333333333 0.6666666666666666
1  11/24/2019       A 0.3333333333333333 0.6666666666666666
2  12/22/2020       A                0.4                0.6
3  15/12/2019       C 0.4444444444444444 0.5555555555555556
4  02/12/2020       C 0.4444444444444444 0.5555555555555556
```